# sql query to do specific matching of demands

Tags: php, mysql, sql, allocation

so I have a small problem whilst working with SQL and PHP. I have a sql db which has 4 tables namely, customers, requests, products and sellers. Now, each table contains self explanatory data. Such as customers tables lists the customers, ids, names, adresses, emails etc., products table has product id and the name, the requests table shows the request of products made by customers with the `request id[pk], custID[fk from customer table], productid[fk in products table], quantites_requested, price_requested`. The sellers table contains data such as `sellersid[pk], customerid[fk from customer table], productsid[fk in products table], quantites_advertised, price_advertised`
Now what I wish to do, is say a customer has requested productid= 1(chocolate),customer id=1, 10kg has been requested for £10.00 So, this data is stored in the DB. 
Now, there might be various sellers of chocolate and what I wish to do is fulfil the customers order i.e. 10kg of chocolates in the cheapest way possible. either by combining sellers or selecting one cheapest seller. So, for example, this is the sellers table. NOTE: the sellers table is structured by following: `sellerid[pk],customerid[fk],productid[fk],quantity_advertised, price_advertised`. so here are some example sellers...

```
1,2,1,4.00,2.00 -- This means customer id 2 is selling chocolates, for 4KG's @£2.00
2,3,1,5.00,2.50
3,4,1,1.00,1.00
4,5,1,10.00,6.00
```

Now we have our requests that state

```
1,1,1,10.00,5.00 -- i.e. customer1, wants chocolates of 10kg for £5.00...
```

Now I wish to fulfil the customers 10kg order. So what I need to do is select the cheapest price for the customer. This could be done by selecting sellers 2,3 and 4 with the kg's of 5,4 and 1kg=10kg which would cost a total of £2.00+£2.50+£1.00=£5.50 cheaper then seller 5 which can supply 10KG for 6.00. I believe I would be able to do something like this using an SQL query where it first matches the customer requests product id to the sellers product id i.e. `SELECT c.Name, p.Name, s.quantity,s.price WHERE c.id=s.customerid AND p.id=s.productid AND s.quantity WHERE r.productid=s.productid FROM requests r, sellers s`
however, how would I be able to select the cheapest option supplier either combined or a single large supplier to take to be the most cost effective? I believe I would need to use the MIN somewhere in the query?

Can someone guide me on how to structure a query as stated. i.e. the full customer request needs to be met in the cheapest way possible.

Comment: Is it possible to redesign your database?  There are issues with yourrs.  For example, your sellers table should not have a customer id.  Also, you need a many to many relationship between products and sellers.

Comment: Yes I could redesign it however, it would mean spending a long time trying to change current code. The thing is the customerid in in sellers since, the customer can be both a person who wishes to buy a product and sell their products. Yes I believe my sellers table does allow this... as the sellers table lists the sellers and the products they are selling??

Answer (score 0):

With your current database design, which I still suggest changing, your query would be something like this:

```
select s.name SellerName
, p.name ProductName
, s.price_advertised price

from sellers s join products p on s.productid = p.productid
join request r on r.productid = p.productid
join (
select sellerid sid
, min(price_advertised) LowestPrice
from sellers ss join request rr on ss.productid = rr.productid
group by sellerid
) sq on sid = s.sellerid and s.advertised_price = LowestPrice
```

This is a simple example.  You'll have to modify it to incorporate requests with more than one product.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I will try and implement it. :)

Comment: I understand your first few lines, however, I am a little confused on what you mean with this `min(price_advertised) LowestPrice
rom` Where do you get this 'Lowest Price and rom' from? I mean what does it mean? And lastly, What does the sq on sid mean? Sorry for the questions I am just a little confused on what you mean by that. And also.. THE sid is an auto-increment primary key in the sellers table where there is incremented by 1 each time the seller lists his product on the site filling the attributes req. e.g. quantities price etc...

Comment: LowestPrice is an alias for min(price_advertised).  rom is the word from without the f.  I have corrected that mistake.